# Convert a function defined in NumPy to SymPy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have a function defined in numpy which I would like to convert to sympy, so I can apply it to symbolic sympy variables. Trying to directly apply the numpy function to a sympy variable fails:

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def np_fun(a):
    return np.array([np.sin(a), np.cos(a)])

x = sp.symbols('x')
sp_fun = np_fun(x)
```

I get the error

```py
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

My next thought was to convert the numpy function to sympy, but I couldn't find a way to do that. I know I could make this code work by just defining the function as a sympy expression:

```py
sp_fun = sp.Array([sp.sin(x), sp.cos(x)])
```

But I'm using the sine/cosine function as a simple example. The actual function I'm using has already been defined in numpy, and is much more complicated, so it would be very tedious to rewrite it.

Comment: `sympy` has the ability to generate `numpy` expressions from its own expressions.  But `sympy` is already working with symbols.  But your `np_fun` is a Python function, even if it calls `numpy` functions.  In the `.py` file it is a string, but in the running session it is already parsed by the interpreter. You can only get at the string version with `inspect` tools.

Comment: `np.fun(x)` calls `np.sin(x)`, which becomes `np.sin(np.array(x))`.  `np.array(x)` is a 0d array with an object element, the `Symbol`.  Faced with that type of array, `np.sin()` tries to do `x.sin()`.  That's the source of your attribute error.  `sympy` symbols can be used in some `numpy` math, but not ones like `np.sin`.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you could directly modify the ast ("abstract syntax tree") of the function, though in practice it might get quite hairy. Anyway, here is how to do it for your simple example:

This creates from the source an ast and derives from the `NodeTransformer` class to modify the ast in-place. The node transformer has a generic visit method that traverses a node and its subtree delegating to node specific visitors in derived classes. Here we change all names `np` to `sp` and afterwards change those attributes to former `np` now `sp` that spell differently. You'd have to add all such differences to the `translate` dict.

Finally, we compile back from the ast to a code object and execute it to make the modified function available.

```
import ast, inspect
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def f(a):
    return np.array([np.sin(a), np.cos(a)])

z = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(f))

translate = {'array': 'Array'}

class np_to_sp(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if node.id=='np':
            node = ast.copy_location(ast.Name(id='sp', ctx=node.ctx), node)
        return node
    def visit_Attribute(self, node):
        self.generic_visit(node)
        if node.value.id=='sp' and node.attr in translate:
            fields = {k: getattr(node, k) for k in node._fields}
            fields['attr'] = translate[node.attr]
            node = ast.copy_location(ast.Attribute(**fields), node)
        return node

np_to_sp().visit(z)

exec(compile(z, '', 'exec'))

x = sp.Symbol('x')
print(f(x))
```

Output:

```
[sin(x), cos(x)]
```

**UPDATE simple enhancement: modify functions called by function:**

```
import ast, inspect
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def f(a):
    return np.array([np.sin(a), np.cos(a)])

def f2(a):
    return np.array([1, np.sin(a)])

def f3(a):
    return f(a) + f2(a)

translate = {'array': 'Array'}

class np_to_sp(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if node.id=='np':
            node = ast.copy_location(ast.Name(id='sp', ctx=node.ctx), node)
        return node
    def visit_Attribute(self, node):
        self.generic_visit(node)
        if node.value.id=='sp' and node.attr in translate:
            fields = {k: getattr(node, k) for k in node._fields}
            fields['attr'] = translate[node.attr]
            node = ast.copy_location(ast.Attribute(**fields), node)
        return node

from types import FunctionType

for fn in f3.__code__.co_names:
    fo = globals()[fn]
    if not isinstance(fo, FunctionType):
        continue
    z = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(fo))
    np_to_sp().visit(z)
    exec(compile(z, '', 'exec'))

x = sp.Symbol('x')
print(f3(x))
```

Prints:

```
[sin(x) + 1, sin(x) + cos(x)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting approach. Do you know how I could modify this so it would work for compositions of functions. For example, if I define `def f2(a): return np.array([1, np.sin(a)])` and `def f3(a): return f(a) + f2(a)` and I wanted to convert `f3` instead of `f`

Comment: @wxyz Sort of, see updated post. Not very robust/general though, but you get the principle.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Find and Replace to modify your numpy function into a sympy expression. You can do it in python using `str.replace()` and defining the rules to replace text as appropriate for your function. If you post your function, it would be easier to provide more specifics.

Comment: Thanks. So are you suggesting I use search and replace to generate additional python code (in a new .py file, for example) in which the new sympy functions are defined?