# How to covert a Python function to SymPy?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, symbolic-math, lambdify

I want to convert a function defined in Python to a symbolic expression in SymPy (`lambdify` does the opposite):

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def fun1(t):
  return t + 3

def fun2(t):
  return np.sin(t)
```

And then convert this `fun1` and `fun2` to a symbolic expression so I can do, for example:

```
x = sp.symbols('x')
fun1s = fun1(x)
fun2s = fun2(x)
```

Then I can differentiate them like:

```
dfun1s = sp.diff(fun1s, x)
dfun2s = sp.diff(fun2s, x)
```

I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55309727/16531346) but it's quite complicated, is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: What you're asking for is, in fact, a complicated question.

Comment: If you want to work with symbolic math in Python you may find [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) useful.  However, it also does not have a way to convert an arbitrary Python function (especially if you're using calls like `np.something`) to a symbolic function.

Comment: I thought that how you can easily do the opposite with lambdify, there would be a easy way to do it

Comment: Not at all.  One is taking an existing [expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) of a fixed set of operators and functions and producing something that evaluates the expression on an input.  The other is parsing and constructing something out of arbitrary Python code.  There are projects which do this for the sake of efficient numerical evaluation, like Numba, but these are extraordinarily complicated.

Comment: Yes that works, I was looking for something easier to deal with, but seems to be very complicated @kwinkunks

Comment: Functions are parsed by the interpreter.  `introspection` tells you about arguments, but (usually) not about code details.  `sympy` expressions have a tokenized tree structure more like the source (and may be parsed from a string).  `lambdify` is a relatively simple lexical translation.  Look at the `help` of a lambdified function.